# Read, Validate and Insert the values of excel file into database using java and jxl

Tags: java, jxl, jxls

I have the following problem statement I am using java and i want to upload a xls file i want to know how i can validate and store the entries of xls file in database using jxl library..

Comment: Pls post some code to show that you have tried something.

Comment: Step 1: Read the jxl APIs, docs, and look at the sample code.  Step 2: ???.  Step 3: Profit!!!

Comment: Can you give me an example or tutorial where i can get this..